# Why doesn't the operating system deny the memory for this program?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, operating-system

The following C++ dynamically allocates memory for huge array for objects which includes huge array of integer.

```
#include <iostream>
// VALUE1 > 1000000
class Int{
int* p = new int[VALUE1];

};

int main() {
// VALUE2 > 1000000
Int* ppi = new Int[VALUE2];
while(true){
    }
}
```

What I understand is the memory is allocated in heap(which is large). The program requests the memory to the OS and it handles the memory allocation. So, my question is why doesn't the OS deny memory to the program(which would make it crash though) if it doesn't have the available memory resource? It's the OS job. The above programs make my computer freeze. I have 8 GB RAM on linux 4.9 if that matters.

Comment: I guess the computer freezes because it is busy doing nothing in `while(true){}`. As `p` and `ppi` are never used they may have been optimized away by the compiler.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler doesn't just optimise the allocation away as you're doing nothing with it?

Comment: Or maybe it is turned into a virtual memory request that won't commit pages until they are accessed.

Comment: I didn't provide the optimization flags as i was just fiddling with to check what would happen. It froze the whole computer and I had to force shutdown. Does compiler optimize dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: You should check what the kernels overcommit value is set to (0 is default) `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`...

Comment: yes, it is zero(the default).

Comment: Insert a sleep() call in the busy-loop, declare p and ppi volatile.  Then consider how much virtual memory your system allows; it will be much larger than the available physical RAM.

Comment: over_commit=0 does not mean no over commit as you might expect http://linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_overcommit_memory.html

Answer (score 1):

> why doesn't the OS deny memory to the program if it doesn't have the available memory resource?

An OS may deny overallocation of memory, or it might not. Not denying over allocation is not something that all OS necessarily do.

Allowing overallocation means that the program is allowed to allocate as much virtual memory as it wants, and won't be terminated until there is no longer free physical memory to map. Physical memory is only mapped when the memory is accessed. Even if all of physical memory is mapped, some of it can be swapped onto the disk.

> on linux 4.9

Linux in particular does support overallocation of memory.

> The above programs make my computer freeze.

The program is an infinite loop. If the loop isn't optimized into a sleep or removed, then it will indefinitely ask for processor time. If there is only 1 CPU core, then depending on the scheduling algorithm, it may take some time for another process to gain CPU time.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a compiler is allowed to remove that loop.